# How to customize number of thumbnail choices on facebook share

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, image, share

I'm using the Ridiculously Responsive Social Sharing Buttons plugin for my posts to be shared on my site. I recently modified the meta property tags on my site so that the featured image + all images attached to a post can be used as thumbnail choices when sharing the post. However, the choices are always limited to 3 even though there are more images attached to the post. How do I specify how many choices I want to appear? For example, there are 10 images on a post I want the users to be able to choose among these 10 images.

Is it on Facebook's side already or is there some kind of code I can add? Or is it a functionality of the plugin?

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Facebook limits this to a maximum number of three thumbnails presented to the user to chose from, and there is nothing you can do to increase that number.

Comment: @CBroe By the way, can you share the article or link where you saw this info from?